# Create and return value assignable to particular key of object

Tags: typescript

I have the following code, that is supposed (in this simplified application), to return a value assignable to a particular key of `Obj`.

```js
interface Obj {
  foo: number;
  bar: string;
}

const foo = createValueOfObjKey("foo");
const bar = createValueOfObjKey("bar");

function createValueOfObjKey<Key extends keyof Obj>(key: Key): Obj[Key] {
  switch (key) {
    case "foo":
      return 0;
    case "bar":
      return "";
  } 
}
```

However, on both the return statements, the compiler complains (exemplified by the `"foo"` return) about not being able to assign to never:

```
Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'Obj[Key]'.
  Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'never'.(2322)
```

*(Funnily enough, the constant's type, holding the return value, is inferred correctly, e.g. `const foo` will be `string`, and `const bar` `number`)*

It seems like typescript isn't able to narrow down `Obj[Key]` to `Obj["foo"]`. So I thought maybe introducing a local variable would help:

```js
    case "foo":
      // I have also tried other things, like Obj[Key].
      const val: Obj[typeof key] = 0;
      return val;
```

But that sadly still results in:

```
Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'Obj[Key]'.
  Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'never'.(2322)
```

I have found the following issues, but I'm uncertain if they are related:

- https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/20907
- https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/10530

[Here the mentioned code as a playground.](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.9.0-dev.20220921#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgPICMBWyDeAoZZGAe2IC5kQBXAW3WgG4Dl04oKBnMKUAcyYC+ePAmIguRUsgC8yBFAhxIANTgAbKhFQwMmANIQAngAoARCWKmAlE1HiwLNjLkKlEVRq06sBk6dZQ1kx4MFQgCGDAYi6KKuqa2rq+ADy+yBAAHpAgACYcyADWRsQwaFgAfMZFhhS+VhS6ANq+ALq4zBwA7sBgCAAWyFVGVu2EhAhwHCjmpKZkzGPIAPRLyACSyH1wAG4o6hzEyNzAEDnIxGB90Ed9fBwANMhqwEVlmM1GLQB0C2N2Ett1A0sI0wIYAA4QEqFT7OAAMTEWhAUYCoUBAyEBakRf0m0wCc1+yIgqPRyFMphxAmQeAEQA)

Comment: This doesn't work because a generic, by definition, allows calls such as `createValueOfObjKey<"foo" | "bar">`. That means you would have to return a string AND a number at the same time, and we know that's *never* possible.

Comment: You can try using [overloads](https://tsplay.dev/wQxO1W) and see how that'll work for you. You will get complaints from TypeScript if you return the wrong type as well.

Comment: Could you fix the example so that you're actually returning the right type for each value?  You've got `{foo: string, bar: number}` but you are returning `number` for `foo` and `string` for `bar`.  Fixing it won't fix the error, but at least you'd actually be demonstrating a problem

Comment: You've run into a TS limitation; see [ms/TS#33014](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/33014) for a suggestion to fix it.  In the meantime there's only workarounds.  For example, does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/N5LgBw) meet your needs? If so I could write up an answer explaining all this; if not, what am I missing? (Please mention @jcalz to notify me in your reply).

Comment: @caTS note that `createValueOfObjKey(Math.random()<0.5 ? "foo" : "bar")` would return a value of type `string | number` (not `string & number`) which is definitely possible.  Indexed access reads are covariant so this wouldn't be a problem if TS could actually follow the logic, which it can't, as per ms/TS#33014.

Comment: @jcalz Thanks for the pointer to the wrongly returned value, I fixed it. Also thanks for finding that issue. May I ask how you find it? I struggled putting it into words when trying to look it up myself.

Comment: I follow the TS GitHub repo issues and some of these situations come up often enough that I remember them.  So, does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/mM1AQm) meet your needs or not?  If so I will write up an answer; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: @jcalz huh, interesting approach. I'm not actually sure if that would fix my issue, because the actual code does much more than that. E.g. calls functions, asynchrony ones, that could even make server requests. The data returned from the server then also needs to be processed a bit.

Comment: Does [this](https://tsplay.dev/w613EW) work better?  I don't know what to say about asynchronous calls; you should edit the example code to be a [mre] if you have some more specific need.  Should I write up an answer or should I go away?

Comment: @jcalz feel free to write an answer. I think the issue you linked, in combination with the workarounds, are a perfectly fine answer. The cherry on top would be, if I could make asynchrone calls, but that might not be possible.

Comment: It *might* be possible but you haven't shown a need for asynchronous calls in your example code so I don't see how you want me to address it.  Maybe it should be a separate question post?  Or maybe you should [edit] the question to show async stuff happening?  I will assume that I can ignore async stuff and write up an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

TypeScript as of TS4.8 cannot use [control flow analysis](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#control-flow-analysis) to narrow or re-constrain [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) type parameters.  So in `createValueOfObjKey(key)` where `key` is of generic type `K extends keyof Obj`, you can check `key` via `switch`, and that will narrow the type of `key`... but `K` itself will stubbornly stay the same.  And therefore the compiler has no idea if a string or a number will be assignable to `Obj[K]` and it complains.

This is currently a missing feature of TypeScript.  There's an open issue at [microsoft/TypeScript#33014](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/33014) asking to add support for code like you've written.  Until and unless that or something like it is implemented, there are only workarounds.

---

The simplest workaround is just to [assert](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions) that what you are doing is correct.  It's the least type safe, but it doesn't require you change your implementation much:

```
function createValueOfObj<K extends keyof Obj>(key: K): Obj[K] {
  switch (key) {
    case "foo":
      return 0 as Obj[K]; // assert
    case "bar":
      return "" as Obj[K]; // assert
  }
  throw new Error("UNREACHABLE"); // compiler can't see exhaustive so you need this 
}
```

---

If you want more type safety, then you need to write something the compiler can verify as accurate.  For an [indexed access type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/indexed-access-types.html) like `T[K]`, the compiler can only easily verify that you've produced a valid value of that type if you take an object of type `t` and a key of type `k` and return the value `t[k]`.  That is, you can perform an indexed access *operation* to get a verifiable indexed access *type*.

So you could write

```
function createValueOfObj<K extends keyof Obj>(key: K): Obj[K] {
  return {
    foo: 0,
    bar: ""
  }[key]; // okay
}
```

That compiles with no error, hooray!

If you're worried that this forces you to come up with all possible output values in advance, you could implement this lookup object lazily via [getters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/get) instead of regular properties:

```
function createValueOfObjKey<K extends keyof Obj>(key: K): Obj[K] {
  return {
    get foo() { return 0 },
    get bar() { return "" }
  }[key]; // okay
}
```

That also compiles with no error, and now only the code corresponding to the actual `key` will be executed.

---

Let's verify that it works:

```
const foo = createValueOfObjKey("foo");
console.log(foo.toFixed(2)) // "0.00"
const bar = createValueOfObjKey("bar");
console.log(bar.toUpperCase()) // ""
```

Looks good.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.8.2#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgPICMBWyDeAoZZGAe2IC5kQBXAW3WgG4Dl04oKBnMKUAcyYC+eYXhhUQCMMGIhkCKBDiQAanAA2VCKhgZMAQQ4doYADwBpZBAAekEABMOyANYQAnsRhosAPgAUL1wozAEoKXQBtMwBdXGYOAHdgMAQAC2R-N2DYwkIEOCNkACISYkKyZhzkBTAqKFkABmR8r0xIqKZKvILC1igyipzq2tlCwqbHCOiO5CFCMBSoYnjKCGWAUShFqF9CgFUAOQAlNb0AYQAJPQAhABk1wuDBYTEJKRk5BSUIVQ0tHSwAJJ2KzmSw2CD2RwBDwtPwBIKhFptbJVCA1OoowglCj1AA0A16FFGzAE4QC7TwQhEL0k0lk8kUKnUmm0ujMblB1lsDmcbhhujhbgRYSwyPwhCGGPFOV4aKIpF8WRwqPRDRm+MqsrALDYitwKuGRTGsxmZLcFKpCBkXHlxGQAF4Pozvsy-my3DsSg8mFaQBxiGoIAA6NTEXi+EpBsDEABiwCsEDsvgATMEsgB6dNFepB+r1Qp4X023oOp1fH4s-6YdmuHa9b2F60B4Oh8O9KPEXYABy70FO+QgiozWeJQA)

Comment: Beautiful answer! Are you still interested in looking into the async stuff? If yes, Would you like it if I appended async code to an existing question (of course explaining the additional context), or rather have me open a new question (do I call it something like "generic type narrowing while using async functions"?)?

Comment: I can't guarantee that I'd get to it, so a new question might be better.  I suppose "generic type narrowing while using async functions" is a reasonable title but I wouldn't know for sure until I saw the body of the question.